# Applovin doesn't launch in iOS application

Tags: ios, sdk, cocos2d-x, applovin

I have a little problem here with Applovin. I have a cocos2d-x project and I need to integrate Applovin there but I can't get it working.

I've done anything which official tutorial says.

I've added AppLovinSdkKey

[image]

I've put -ObjC flag

[image]

And I've done all needed coding

```
    -(void) initApplovin
{
    [ALSdk initializeSdk];
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = self;
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adLoadDelegate = self;
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adVideoPlaybackDelegate = self;
}
-(void) showApplovin
{
    if ([ALInterstitialAd isReadyForDisplay]) {
        [ALInterstitialAd show];
    }   else    {
        NSLog(@"Applovin isn't ready for showing banners");
    }
}
```

So as you can see, it seems that I've done all things properly but I'm pretty sure I missed some tiny detail. Please, help me out! :)

P.S.: All advertising code I've put to RootViewController. By the way, Chartboost in RootViewController too and it works absolutely perfect

Comment: Hi, Eugene

Maybe you can help me. I too was unable to see the ads. I saw that you had 
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = self;
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adLoadDelegate = self;
    [ALInterstitialAd shared].adVideoPlaybackDelegate = self;
while I didn't have this.
I added this and got a warning "assigning to 'id<AlsAdDisplayDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible tyoe 'appDelegate *const_strong'

by the way I didn;t build a special method init but put all this code straight to "didfinishedlaunchingwithoptions"

And I still don't see the any ad

I'll happy for any help

Comment: Hello, Tomer! It seems like you need to put delegate in your header file. You can google some sort of request "delegates in ios", and everything will become clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I've figured out the problem.
If you have a problem with Applovin, just be patient. When you do all the coding needed and Applovin still doesn't work, here what you should do:

1. Give it a time. It can be like 30 minutes till Applovin load your application to your account. If you've already tried it, and it couldn't work out, go for 2 paragraph.
2. Try to create new account. I've won fight with Applovin after I've created new clear account
3. If you finally could initialize your application in Applovin system, **DON'T FORGET** to put test mode available. Also give this option couple of minutes before it will be activated.
4. And guys, **THE MAIN THING**. If you're trying to install applovin in cocos2d-x application, **don't put the code to RootViewController**. I know, Revmob, Chartboost and other frameworks work fine here, but it seems that Applovin doesn't. I tried to launch banner from RootViewController and I catch the error but when I put this code to AppController, everything worked like a charm.